# Viewcontroller not appearing since iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios7

Edit - I solved this myself - see the notes at the bottom

When using iOS7 on Xcode 5, I am using an option to take an image from a camera, or from the photo library, once the image is chosen (or a new picture taken) the view should flip over to the next screen.

This does not happen on the iPhone running iOS7, it works fine on the iPad, but the method is slightly different, but it does appear to be iPhone only problem on iOS7.

here is the code used, for example, on the choose image from library function;

```
-(void) choosePic {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum]) {
        UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        cameraUI.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];
        cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;
        cameraUI.delegate = self;

        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            _popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:cameraUI];
            [_popover presentPopoverFromRect:btnLibrary.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];


        }
        else

            [self presentModalViewController: cameraUI animated: YES];

    }    
}
```

Also, the code once picker is finished;

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info { 
    //Disable buttons

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

    [self disableButtons];

    //Get image
    self.originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    //Dismiss
    if(_popover)
    {
        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            [_popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
            _popover = nil;
        }
    }
    else
        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

    //Next
    [self performSelector: @selector(nextScreen) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}
```

I fixed this by switching out;

```
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

With

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure that logic reaches the correct place it's intended to, try setting a breakpoint or NSLog before the iPhone's specific line, try this (You also missed curled braces, added them here) :

```
-(void) choosePic {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum]) {
        UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        cameraUI.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];
        cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;
        cameraUI.delegate = self;

        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            _popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:cameraUI];
            [_popover presentPopoverFromRect:btnLibrary.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];


        }else{
            NSLog(@"Checkpoint !");
            [self presentModalViewController: cameraUI animated: YES];
        }

    }     }
```

Comment: Hey Mostafa, Yep, I get the Checkpoint in the log, the picker appears, it seems to be once the image is chosen, the picker dismisses, then it is meant to flip the screen but it doesn't, it just stays at the main menu screen without flipping (iOS6 and below works fine) although I do see this in the console...
`2013-09-22 18:14:43.372[3977:60b] Warning: Attempt to present <LoadingViewController: 0x177839d0> on <TakePictureViewController: 0x15d6ec30> while a presentation is in progress!`